# Django: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I'm using django with jquery to upload files using ajax. However, after the file has uploaded (and the files do upload correctly; the database is updated and they are on the server) javascript returns with an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.

I don't know if this is an error in javascript or an error in django; other questions I saw seemed to recommend making sure the information is indeed in JSON format, but it seems to be properly formatted in my case. I don't really understand why there is an error, since everything seems to work fine. There are no errors in my logs.

If I could only see a more helpful error message, I would have a much easier time fixing the issue.

Here's my views.py:

```
def response_mimetype(request):
    if "application/json" in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']:
        return "application/json"
    else:
        return "text/plain"

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSON response class."""

    def __init__(self,obj='',json_opts={},mimetype="application/json",*args,**kwargs):
        content = simplejson.dumps(obj,**json_opts)
        a = super(JSONResponse,self).__init__(content,mimetype,*args,**kwargs)

class UploadedFileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UploadedFile
    form_class = UploadedFileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.project_id = self.kwargs['proj_key']
        self.object.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')

        data = [{
            'name': self.object.name(),
            'url': "/uploads/xmlfiles/" + self.object.name().replace(" ", "_"),
            'delete_url': reverse('fileupload:upload-delete',
                kwargs={'pk':self.object.id,
                'proj_key':self.kwargs['proj_key']}),
            'delete_type': "DELETE"}]

        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))

        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'

        return super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['files'] = UploadedFile.objects.all()
        context['proj'] = int(self.kwargs["proj_key"])
        return context
```

And here's my models.py:

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    """This represents a file that has been uploaded to the server."""
    STATE_UPLOADED = 0
    STATE_ANNOTATED = 1
    STATE_PROCESSING = 2
    STATE_PROCESSED = 4
    STATES = (
        (STATE_UPLOADED, "Uploaded"),
        (STATE_ANNOTATED, "Annotated"),
        (STATE_PROCESSING, "Processing"),
        (STATE_PROCESSED, "Processed"),
    )

    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATES,
        default=0, blank=True, null=True) 
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.XML_ROOT)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

    def name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.status:
            self.status = self.STATE_UPLOADED
        super(UploadedFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.remove(self.file.path)
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(UploadedFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/upload/projects/%d' % self.id 

class UploadedFileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
        exclude = ('project',)
```

Comment: Try it in Chrome, open DevTools and make sure you click on "pause on uncaught exceptions" toggle on the "sources" tab.  This will help you localize the error and hopefully move to the next step of debugging.

Comment: You're creating your `JSONResponse` instance, but not returning it from your view. Your JSON call is getting whatever `super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).form_valid` returns - an HTTP redirect, if memory serves.

Comment: Always look at what is returned from the server, use the net tab in your console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example), the `form_valid()` method needs to return the JSON  as a `HTTPResponse`. Calling the `form_valid()` on the super class will, instead, overwrite the response created on the previous two lines.

**Edit -** This is working for me:

```
def response_mimetype(request):
  if "application/json" in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']:
    return "application/json"
  else:
    return "text/plain"

class UploadedFileCreateView(CreateView):
  model = UploadedFile
  form_class = UploadedFileForm

  def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.project_id = self.kwargs['proj_key']
    self.object.save()
    f = self.request.FILES.get('file')

    data = [{
      'name': self.object.name(),
      'url': "/uploads/xmlfiles/" + self.object.name().replace(" ", "_"),
      'type': "application/xml",
      'size': self.object.file.size,
      'delete_url': reverse('fileupload:upload-delete',
        kwargs={'pk':self.object.id,
        'proj_key':self.kwargs['proj_key']}),
      'delete_type': "DELETE"}]

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), content_type = response_mimetype(self.request))
```

The code in the link above bundles the ajax response code as a Mixin which would allow other forms in the project to reuse the code.

Viewing the response to the Ajax call in the Firefox plugin Firebug, Net tab or Chrome equivalent will help. These will show both the request and response headers ensuring the correct settings are being sent and returned.

Comment: With your code, I get `Empty file upload result` as a javascript error, though there don't seem to be javascript exceptions in the console.

Comment: ah ok, can you post your html / javascript? Then I'd be happy to debug the code properly, ;).

Comment: Thanks so much! Here's my template:
https://github.com/PlasmaSheep/wseer/blob/master/wseeruploader/apps/fileupload/templates/fileupload/uploadedfile_form.html

And it references javascript here:

https://github.com/PlasmaSheep/wseer/tree/master/wseeruploader/apps/fileupload/static/js

Comment: @Plasma I've debugged a clone from github and the edited `form_valid()` in my post above is working with the `jquery-file-upload` plugin in firefox for me. Great looking project, btw.

Comment: This fixes my issue. Thanks for going the extra mile!